# Increase fan speed

Tags: bios, fan, gpu, laptop-repair

I'm currently trying to speed up my fan in an attempt to keep my laptop cooler and running a lot smoother when gaming.

I've tried using programs such as speedfan and these can't access my fan. I have read loads of reviews about HP Pavilions and assume this was in consequence of a BIOS update.  (I didn't want it but a new BIOS was installed on my laptop when sent for repairs and that's when this problem started.) I think my fan is starting to speed up too late and my laptop becomes very over heated.

So any help on how to speed up the fan and leave it running at a maximum speed?

Comment: Need your specific model of laptop, not just "HP Pavilion"; also, your operating system and version would be helpful.

Comment: Sent in for repairs? Any chance they re-seated the CPU heatsink without applying a new layer of heatsink compound? A heatsink with poor contact will give these symptoms.

Comment: if you have the same model as me (pavilion dv 6000) or similar architecture, you cant change the fan speeds. this is caused by the fans connecting to the PSU directly instead of connecting to the motherboard, therefore making speed control impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If your bios isnt locked by HP then in BIOS, there is a option, that makes fan run at maximum speed all the time. But this is very loud...

It looks like this :

http://goo.gl/nAnLi2

if there is not this options, there is an option which says: FAN ALWAYS ON? and you choose YES.